# CKEditor automatically removes style attribute and add xss attribute 'Removed'

Tags: javascript, php, html, ckeditor

CKEditor automatically removes style attribute and add xss attribute 'removed' like if I put a style attribute in a element:

```
<div class="text-center" style="text-align: center;">Test Heading</div>
```

After save I got the following output:

```
<div class="text-center" xss="removed">Test Heading</div>
```

My configuration is:

```
var toolbar_custom=[
    { name: 'document', items: [ 'Source' ] },
    { name: 'editing', items: [ 'Scayt' ] },
    { name: 'basicstyles', items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph', items: ['JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock'] },
    { name: 'insert', items: [ 'Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak', 'Iframe' ] },
    { name: 'links', items: [ 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor' ] },
    { name: 'styles', items: [ 'Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize' ]}

];

jQuery(function(){
        CKEDITOR.replace('template_editor_custom',{
            uiColor:'#2778a7', 
            toolbar:toolbar_custom,
            autoParagraph:false,
            enterMode:CKEDITOR.ENTER_DIV,
            allowedContent:true,
            extraAllowedContent:'*{*}'
        })
    });
```

Html:

```
<textarea class="form-control textbox-style" id="template_editor_custom" name="page[content]" placeholder="Page content"><?php echo set_value('page[content]', $content); ?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm using **CKEditor** in **CodeIgniter**

It's worked using 2nd argument of $this->input->post('filed_name', FALSE)

**Input Text**

```
<div style="background-color:#eee; padding:15px">
    <span style="font-size:16px;"> <u>Friendly Reminder</u> </span>
</div>
```

**Example 1**

```
<?php
    echo html_escape($this->input->post('template_editor_custom'));
?>
```

**Output**

```
<div xss=removed>
    <span xss=removed> <u>Friendly Reminder</u> </span>
</div>
```

**Example 2**

```
<?php
    echo html_escape($this->input->post('template_editor_custom', FALSE));
?>
```

**Output**

```
<div style="background-color:#eee; padding:15px">
    <span style="font-size:16px;"> <u>Friendly Reminder</u> </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's no an issue of CKEditor.
I suspect you are using CodeIgniter 2.x and you have enabled 'Global XSS Filtering'. You need to turn it off in you config file:

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;
```

`xss=removed` is typical sanitizing method used in CodeIgniter.

Comment: No, I am using CI v3.1.X, and I solved the problem by overriding core/Security.php file removed style restriction from the list. If I set global xss filtering to false, it compromises the entire site security.

Comment: You should not override a Core file, that's very bad practice. No one should override a core file. Actually setting FALSE will not cause a problem because new version from 3.*.*, they are not using it, it is there just for old compatibility. Or you can use `$this->input->post($template_editor_custom, FALSE);`

Answer (score 1):

I solve my problem by changing the core/Security.php file.
Just go to _sanitize_naughty_html function and remove style tag from these two static array:

```
static $naughty_tags    = array(
            'alert', 'prompt', 'confirm', 'applet', 'audio', 'basefont', 'base', 'behavior', 'bgsound',
            'blink', 'body', 'embed', 'expression', 'form', 'frameset', 'frame', 'head', 'html', 'ilayer',
            'iframe', 'input', 'button', 'select', 'isindex', 'layer', 'link', 'meta', 'keygen', 'object',
            'plaintext', 'style', 'script', 'textarea', 'title', 'math', 'video', 'svg', 'xml', 'xss'
        );

        static $evil_attributes = array(
            'on\w+', 'style', 'xmlns', 'formaction', 'form', 'xlink:href', 'FSCommand', 'seekSegmentTime'
        );
```

I solved the problem like this way without compromising my entire site security. In future if you want to upgrade your CI version then after upgrading find these two array inside _sanitize_naughty_html function in Security.php and remove the style tag from these two list.

Thank You.

Comment: Nope... editing the core is never the solution - submit a bug if you think it's wrong!

Comment: Thank you, didn't know that it exist. @whitatom it's not wrong nor a bug, It's just personal preferences of what you think can be safely allowed in the security.

Answer (score 0):

There is no any issue with CKEDITOR

Turn off from `config` file as below it will work

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;
```